# How do I create an android AIR app with more than one page or doc using Flash (Professional CS6)

Tags: android, flash, mobile, air, flash-cs6

I'm learning creating mobile android AIR apps using Flash Professional CS6.

I want to try and create a game where first there is a title screen, and then when you press play you go to the game screen.

But I can't figure out how to create an app where there are such multiple pages/docs/screens allowing you to navigate from one to the next.

If you create one .fla file then everything seems to be on the one page. Maybe the way is to create multiple .fla files, one for each screen and then in some way navigate between them? (No idea how.) Or should you have one .fla file and create the different pages as points in the timeline (sounds cumbersome and awful!).

My question is how would you achieve the above, and what is the recommended and simplest way of doing it?

There seem to be very little resources and tutorials about creating AIR apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of ways to do that, it depends a bit on the scale of your project and your knowledge level.

1. In 'basic' flash you simply could jump to a new frame or scene containing your animations.
   I'm not recommending this for a game project, as a lot of things normally change in the making and adusting all the gotoFrame() calls can be a a pain in the ... , ah well, you know where.
2. A cleaner approach would be to make your animations/ screens into separate .swf files or pack them all into an .swc, where you can instantiate them from, when you need them. Don't do any scripting in here, but use a centralized controller instead, that will coordinate loading and displaying the screens. E.g., you may add a Loader() in your root to load and add new scene contained in an .swf or instantiate a class from the .swc.
3. Especially when writing a (2D) game, you should definately check out the Starling Framework for Flash. It requires some basic knowledge of object oriented programming, though. A lot of resources can be found at the big G using "starling framework tutorial" as search term.
   It's using Stage3D as basis and this way is a lot faster than rendering your content the normal flash way. The api is using very similar concepts as 'original' flash, but is a bit different in the detail. If you are starting to learn OOP, you could start here as well and get used to Starling right from the beginning.

The scope of this question is a bit broad to be answered in a post, though.
I'd suggest you get going, and ask more questions, when you encounter a specific problem :-)
Good luck!

Comment: @user3485022 Hi. did you find this helpful? If so, please mark it accepted or leave a comment

Comment: Hi there, thanks very much. For option 2 - if there a good resource for a tutorial/sample code?

Comment: There's loads of tutorials out there. Google brings up lot's of hits like this [one](http://as3gametuts.com/2011/03/19/pong-1/). As for the export of game assets as swf, just take a look [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b8ea63-7fee.html)